# Apache DbUtils handler for single row query result

Tags: java, database, apache-commons-dbutils

I need to select single row and store it attributes into `List<String>`, but I do not know what handler could fit.

More formal:

```
QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner();;
List<String> row = runner.query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?", new Handler(), id);
```

Comment: Can you share your full code sample?

Comment: I have made an update of the code sample, is it full enough?